# Uso de typename fuera de plantillas

Tags: c++

Estoy utilizando un TAD genérico, y debo construir un modulo E/S sobre él. ¿Podría crear un objeto de cierto tipo (supongamos int o char) y que las funciones de E/S recibieran un objeto tipo Typename T para que puedan servirme para ambos tipos? ¿O por el contrario debería crear varias funciones E/S mediante sobrecarga de funciones?

Comment: Pues, lo que se me ocurre es que dentro de la clase que define tu TAD, puedes definir la sobrecarga de los operadores de extracción (>>) y de inserción (<<) pero no como funciones miembro de la clase, sino como funciones externas, sin embargo, para que estas puedan tener acceso a las variables miembro privadas, las funciones deberán ser amigas de la clase usando la palabra reservada friend, haciendo esto, tendrás la entrada de valores (operador <<) y salida (operador >>) sobrecargado listo para los objetos de tu clase TAD.

Answer (score 0):

El título de tu pregunta no se corresponde con el cuerpo de la misma. El uso de `typename` fuera de plantillas es la creación de alias de tipos:

```
typename int entero; // 'entero' es un alias de 'int'.
```

A partir de C++11 los alias de tipos también se pueden crear con `using`:

```
using entero = int; // 'entero' es un alias de 'int'.
```

Dicho eso, respecto al cuerpo de tu pregunta:

> ¿Podría crear un objeto de cierto tipo (supongamos int o char) y que las funciones de E/S recibieran un objeto tipo Typename T para que puedan servirme para ambos tipos?

La pregunta no es si podrías, porque por poder se puede:

```
template <typename T>
void TAD(T t)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
}
```

Se puede usar así:

```
int main()
{
    TAD(1);
    TAD('1');
    return 0;
}
```

Y [muestra la siguiente salida](https://tio.run/##JYzLCsIwEEXXzlcMuEi7EOy2LQXxAW6qSFwIQghpkEAzDe1UEPHbY6u7w@Gea0JYmVbTI8alI9OOjcXSdQP3VvsKgK0PreZJ8itY0t6irODZuQblZpdI5BTesBi4yXPTjYxliUqdL3spb@pwrbfyeKqVmrW4kyjgA@CI0WtHyS@db7K0@IPIxIy95bEnXE/zGL8):

> ```
> void TAD(T) [T = int]
> void TAD(T) [T = char]
> ```

El problema es que una plantilla acepta **todos** los tipos que le puedas pasar, sin embargo tú quieres limitarte a ciertos tipos. Si quieres que los tipos no permitidos impidan la compilación de tu código deberías usar sobrecarga.